# How come this series is convergent?

Tags: analysis

How does the below series converges

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}.$$

I used ratio test and got 1 (which means divergent). But i was told the series is convergent, i don't understand.

Edit: Thank you all. I understand now. :)

Comment: It's convergent due to the Leibniz criterion. The ratio test doesn't tell you anything if the limit is 1.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. By the way, its value is $-\ln2$.

Comment: @Presage Not true. The ratio test only cares about $\lim_{n\to\infty}|u_{n+1}/u_n|$.

Comment: Suggestion: Read about "alternating series".

Answer (score 3):

No the 1 you got means it's inconclusive (no conclusion possible with this test) and you need to use another method

Answer (score 1):

The ratio test fails if you get the value as 1, for a counter example $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$ has 1 as limit of ratios where the former series diverges and the latter one converges. To know why $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges you need to know a theorem on "alternating series" by Leibnitz. This theorem is stated as follows:

Suppose
(a) $\left\lvert c_1 \right\rvert$ $\geqslant$ $\left\lvert c_2 \right\rvert$ $\geqslant$ $\left\lvert c_3 \right\rvert$ . . . ;
(b) $c_{2m-1}$ $\leqslant$ 0 , $c_{2m}$ $\geqslant$ 0  (m=1 , 2 , 3 ,. . .);
(c) $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $c_{n}$ = 0

Then  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n$ converges.

Here your $c_n$ = $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, which clearly satisfies all the above mentioned condition. Thats the reason why $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges.

Answer (score -1):

As a hint: $\frac1n\to0$ and $$(-1)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\\=\frac11-\frac 1{2}+\frac 13-\frac 14+\frac 15-\frac 16+\cdots\\=\left(\frac11-\frac 1{2}\right)+\left(\frac 13-\frac 14\right)+\left(\frac 15-\frac 16\right)+\cdots\\=\frac 12 +\frac 1{12}+\frac 1{30}+\cdots\\<\left(\frac11-\frac 12\right)+\left(\frac12-\frac 13\right)+\left(\frac13-\frac 14\right)+\cdots=1.$$

Comment: isn't this overkill?

Comment: In the case of a conditionally convergent series, like the alternate harmonic series, your manipulation would require some explanation.

Comment: I fixed this answer, to adress these 3 comments. I think the downvotes can be changed to upvotes now. This method is more elementary than the alternating series test.

Comment: @peterwhy: Thank you for turning lantern. If I say $$\frac 12 +\frac 1{12}+\frac 1{30}+\cdots<1+\frac12 +\frac 14 +\frac 18 +\frac 1{16}+\cdots$$ it is okey?

Comment: The LHS denominators are $(i+1)(i+2)$ while the RHS denominators are $2^i$, so term-wise the RHS denominators will eventually be larger, and the LHS fractions will be larger. (From $\frac1{17\cdot 18}$ vs. $\frac1{512}$ onwards.)

Comment: @peterwhy: Yes yes. I got the point now. thanks a lot.